# Posting form to an iframe under strict XHTML (firefox)

Tags: forms, firefox, iframe, xhtml

For debug purposes, I run my page under strict XHTML while I develop it. But, right now, I realised, that such code will not work:

```
<!-- With header("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=\"utf-8\"") -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--blah blah blah-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" target="my_frame">
      <button>Send the form!</button>
    </form>
    <iframe name="my_frame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try it [here](http://u8.8u.cz/xhtmlform.php). And also try it [with `text/html` content-type](http://u8.8u.cz/xhtmlform.php?nostrict). I can, of course, disable the strict mode for the site, but here on SO my question is, how to get it to work a XHTML. (this means, how to make the 1. link work properly).
<sub>**Fun fact:** While testing the example, I noticed that `<button>` tag does not work in IE properly. Any ideas what's wrong? (that's side question of course)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For XHTML, use `id` rather than `name` as the attribute for the target on the iframe. For HTML/XHTML compatibility, use both a `name` and an `id` and make sure their values are the same.
   However, take note that `target` is not a valid attribute on a form. So it won't validate, and its working is not guaranteed.
2. The IE one should have been another question, but IE needs `type="submit"` for buttons, even if that type is supposed to be the default.

Comment: `type` is a valid attribute for `button`?

Comment: Using `id` along with `name` for `<iframe>` helped. Thank you.